# Unable to load and display a frontend React element loaded as a third-party script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to build a tool that will utilize local storage to read/write some data about a session when a user visits my website.

Ultimately I'd like to display this information back to the user as a fixed div or "window" on the page that would just display the values stored in `localStorage`.

Given that I'm comfortable in React, I'd like to use React to build the *display* window portion of this project. (Again, it would ideally just be reading/writing to `localStorage`, seems simple enough.)

The caveat though is that I won't be using it in a full React application. The pre-existing website I want to display the window on is vanilla js/html/css.

So I was hoping that I could utilize a tool like Webpack to export/bundle the React app Component portion as a single js file, which I would load and initiate display of like any other third-party javascript library.

```
<script
  async
  src="//www.mysite.org/frontend-bundle.js"
></script>
```

However...all my attempts at this have been failures.

At this point, I'm back at square one. I'm trying to use `create-react-app` to spin up a fresh React app and *this* is what I'd like to display in the window on the site just as a proof of concept.

I have updated my npm scripts to first do a React build. Then take all of the built `.js` files and bundle them as a single js file. The `webpack.config.js` for that looks like this:

```
const path = require("path")
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin")
const glob = require("glob")

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "bundle.js": glob.sync("build/static/?(js|css)/*.?(js|css)").map(f => path.resolve(__dirname, f)),
  },
  output: {
    filename: "build/static/js/bundle.min.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [new UglifyJsPlugin()],
}
```

This seems to be building properly and to test, I've added a basic `console.log('Hello, World!');` inside the main `App.js` to let me know it's been loaded. I see this console log when I view the source of the bundle file.

However, when I load this bundle file from the server as a `<script>` tag on the page, I see the file loads fine in the browser networking tab, but no console log. Nothing executes, and nothing is rendered.

Is there something obvious I'm missing and/or should I be thinking about this in a totally different way?

Appreciate any insight!

Comment: Can you provde your html where you placing your <script> ? As well as index.html and index.js from you actual sources?